# How to store multiple images in a MongoDB collection using a Python script?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I would like to store multiple images from a folder in a mongodb collection. I started off as follows:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017) # I connected to the mongo instance running on the system

db = client['database1']    # I connected to the required data base
```

If I were to create a collection and insert data into it, I do the following:

```
people = db['details'] #I created a new collection named people.

p1 = { "name" : "Dravid", "age" : 22 }
people.insert(p1)
```

But, I would like to create a collection (say "images") and insert images into this new collection from a folder (the path of the folder is known). Is it possible ? If yes, how do I do it ? And how to visualize the images that are stored in the database ?

Comment: You can do using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: @ManojJadhav I will be grateful if you could give a more specific answer or an illustration to my question.